Xcode error when Im runing webdriver agent project
“WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj” is currently locked because you are not the owner of the file and do not have write permission.
I get this error when i do product > Test
I also can see a lock symbol next to the project selected
Trouble shooted : by opening the project in the terminal > get info > provide the read&write permission yet the same issue ,
please help to resolve this

how did you install appium ?

sudo npm install -g appium

You need to give the access to WebDriverAgent.proj via terminal. Use these commands:

cd /Users/yourusername/Projects/WebDriverAgent - navigate to the project (for finding the path use sudo find . -name "appium-webdriveragent", it will take more than 5 minutes to find it)

sudo chown -R userName WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj - part for permission

sudo chmod -R u+rw WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj - part for permission

ls -l WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj - command for checking if the user is added to the list for access


